# Pyramid BeforeRender subscribtion and accessing .request

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyramid

I've a subscriber function to BeforeRender event.
Each time a request is made, this function is being called.

Here I want to analyse the given request url but I fail in accessing the request.application_url or request.route_url

How can I get the requested url and print it in the console each time a request's been made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event['request']` will yield the `request` object you need. From there you can look at various properties, all of which are [documented](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/request.html). For example `request.path_info` will be the `/path/to/this/view`.

`BeforeRender` is only invoked when a renderer is used on a view or `render()` or `render_to_response()` are called. For *every* request you can use a `NewRequest` event or `ContextFound`.

Comment: Hello Michael. Thank you very much for your answer. I needed this to solve "the" slash issue. I thought if I check the url each time there's a request with a slash at the end, I could do a redirect since somehow Pyramid sucks at this URL handling business. But then I solved this by modifying the not_found_view. Thank you though, great help! PS. Since you are directly involved with Pyramid, I would like to suggest you to check PHP Framework Kohana's URL handling system. It total rocks and a million times more solid and better than Pyramids. I believe it is how all frameworks should handle URLs.

Comment: What is "the" slash issue? Have you seen the `append_slash` option to the notfound view?

Comment: I've seen it. Read the docs extensively, big fan of Pyramid here. However that solution is not really good as I don't want to have all my URLs ending with a slash, it should work both ways out of the box. This is the issue. Most people would like the opposite of what's offered. Unlike URLs to end with slash, to have the possibility of having it or not. Framework should handle this and make it as a feature for those who want to have different handlers for ../a and ../a/ This not being handled is an issue. I redirect all 404s to notfoundview, there I check if URL ends with a slash if so redirect

Comment: I'd be happy to expand on this in an issue that you open on github. However there are ways to implement this seamlessly in Pyramid, and good reasons that it is not supported out of the box as a default.

Comment: Michael, thank you for keep responding. Yes, there are of course multiple possible solutions here and I am sure you are correct that the reasons are legit and good for not supporting it out of the box. However, I personally believe it should be as easy as .add_route(.., .., redirect_slash="True") for example. Secondly, if you have the time, please check Kohana's URL system. It is really remarkable unlike anything out there. Supports optional segments, allows much easier restriction, limitations, better regex support and such. If Pyramid were to have this, it would truly outshine the rest.